# Infinite loop(?) when trying to use .hasNext() when reading from a file

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

I'm trying to have Java count the number of lines within a text file using `hasNext()`, `hasNextLine()`, and while loops although I seem to be having some trouble. The program will continuously run and I believe it's stuck in an infinite loop. If someone could explain the issue and give me a possible fix I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here's the file the program is reading from (hurcdata2.txt, its saved in the program's directory):

```
1980 Aug    945 100 Allen
1983 Aug    962 100 Alicia
1984 Sep    949 100 Diana
1985 Jul    1002    65  Bob
1985 Aug    987 80  Danny
1985 Sep    959 100 Elena
1985 Sep    942 90  Gloria
1985 Oct    971 75  Juan
1985 Nov    967 85  Kate
```

And here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class HurricaneData
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File hurricaneData = new File("TestText.txt");
        Scanner inFileHD = new Scanner(hurricaneData);
        int n = 0; //represents number of blocks of data
        while( inFileHD.hasNextLine() )
        {  
           n++;
        }
        System.out.println(n + " block of data");
        inFileHD.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consume the input to the Scanner otherwise `inFileHD.hasNextLine()` will always be `true`

```
while (inFileHD.hasNextLine()) {
    inFileHD.nextLine(); // add this
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick explanation. I thought it automatically consumed the data. Whoops.